# How can I update my local repository according to the remotly repository?

Tags: git, gerrit

I did some changes and I dirty the local repository.
How can I update  my local repo to be exactly like the remotly repo (and also update all the submodules)?

I thought to do `git pull --rebase`  but I not sure if it's will give me what that I want.

Comment: `git reset --hard` will revert your local project to the last checkin.  It's usually exactly what you want - but 1) it can leave "cruft", and 2) your last local checkin might be different from the current remote's HEAD.  Another "simple" approach: re-clone the remote into a new folder.

Answer (score 1):

use `git fetch` to sync with the remote

then delete untracked files:

```
git clean -xfd
git submodule foreach --recursive git clean -xfd
```

then reset changes:

```
git reset --hard origin/main #update the name branch if needed
git submodule foreach --recursive git reset --hard
```

Reinit submodules:

```
git submodule update --init --recursive
```

Full set:

```
git fetch
git clean -xfd
git submodule foreach --recursive git clean -xfd
git reset --hard
git submodule foreach --recursive git reset --hard
git submodule update --init --recursive
```

Comment: where i need to run these commands ?

Comment: It's not solved my question. After that i running the full set you mentioned, so after I running `git status` I see commits from some yeras ago (in the head). @Ôrel

Comment: I need to do checkout to some commit/branch before that I running the "Full Set" ? How can I see after that I running the "Full Set" the most updated commit on the master ? @Ôrel

Comment: you can add an argument after `git reset --hard origin/<branch>` to select the branch you want to target. Please describe if you did some git change or just files modification

Comment: I want to clear all the things that i did (removing files, adding of files, changes of code in files). And I want to finally to be on the top of master branch (on the newest commit there).
For example: I did `git checkout <some SHA>` and I edited the code there and i removed & added files there. And more dirties..
So I want to clear everything and to update my local repository (include the submodules and everything that I can update) to be like the remotly repository.

Comment: I have updated the answer to reset to the origin branch. Another solution can be to delete and clone again